# XSLT Transformation get element based on condition and map it to sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transfrom xml with the below rule. Iam stuck in transformation.

Rule as below:

For each match of ns1:Account/ns3:Policies/ns3:Policy/ns3:PolicyConditions/ns3:PolicyCondition/ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria/ns3:Value that matches with ns1:Account/ns3:Locations/ns3:Name.I need to get the value of ns1:Account/ns3:Policies/ns3:Policy/ns3:PolicyConditions/ns3:PolicyCondition/ns2:ItemData and create new tag and map it to ns1:Account/ns3:Locations/ns3:LocationConditions/ns3:LocationCondition/ns2:ConditionId and hardcode ns1:Account/ns3:Locations/ns3:LocationConditions/ns3:LocationCondition/ns2:ConditionId to 0

Attached sample input and expected output

Input XML:

```
<ns1:Account xmlns:ns1="API.ExposureWorkflow">
   <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
   <ns3:Locations xmlns:ns3="API.Objects.Exposure">
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Name>
      </ns3:Location>
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC2-BU1</ns3:Name>
      </ns3:Location>
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC2-BU3</ns3:Name>
      </ns3:Location>
   </ns3:Locations>
   <ns3:Policies xmlns:ns3="API.Objects.Exposure">
      <ns3:Policy>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:PolicyConditions>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias/>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ItemData xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">28</ns2:ItemData>
               <ns3:Name>EQ Blanket28</ns3:Name>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC2-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
               </ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ItemData xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">29</ns2:ItemData>
               <ns3:Name>EQ Blanket29</ns3:Name>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC2-BU3</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
               </ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
         </ns3:PolicyConditions>
      </ns3:Policy>
   </ns3:Policies>
</ns1:Account>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:ns1="API.ExposureWorkflow" xmlns:ns2="API.Objects" xmlns:ns3="API.Objects.Exposure">
                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>



                <!-- template to copy elements -->
                <xsl:template match="*">
                                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                </xsl:template>
                <!-- template to copy attributes -->
                <xsl:template match="@*">
                                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:template>
                <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
                <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
                                <xsl:copy/>
                </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected ouput:

```
<ns1:Account xmlns:ns1="API.ExposureWorkflow">
   <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
   <ns3:Locations xmlns:ns3="API.Objects.Exposure">
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Name>
          <ns3:LocationConditions>
            <ns3:LocationCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ConditionId xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">28</ns2:ConditionId>
            </ns3:LocationCondition>
            <ns3:LocationCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ConditionId xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">29</ns2:ConditionId>
            </ns3:LocationCondition>
      </ns3:LocationConditions>
      </ns3:Location>
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC2-BU1</ns3:Name>
         <ns3:LocationConditions>
            <ns3:LocationCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ConditionId xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">28</ns2:ConditionId>
            </ns3:LocationCondition>
      </ns3:LocationConditions>
      </ns3:Location>
      <ns3:Location>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:Name>LOC2-BU3</ns3:Name>
         <ns3:LocationConditions>
            <ns3:LocationCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ConditionId xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">29</ns2:ConditionId>
            </ns3:LocationCondition>
      </ns3:LocationConditions>
      </ns3:Location>
   </ns3:Locations>
   <ns3:Policies xmlns:ns3="API.Objects.Exposure">
      <ns3:Policy>
         <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
         <ns3:PolicyConditions>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias/>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ItemData xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">28</ns2:ItemData>
               <ns3:Name>EQ Blanket28</ns3:Name>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC2-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
               </ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
            <ns3:PolicyCondition>
               <ns2:Id xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:ItemData xmlns:ns2="API.Objects">29</ns2:ItemData>
               <ns3:Name>EQ Blanket29</ns3:Name>
               <ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC1-BU1</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                  <ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
                     <ns3:Value>LOC2-BU3</ns3:Value>
                  </ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria>
               </ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias>
            </ns3:PolicyCondition>
         </ns3:PolicyConditions>
      </ns3:Policy>
   </ns3:Policies>
</ns1:Account>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we're not a code-writing service.  What, specifically, are you hung up on?  The XSL you provided is just a needlessly-complex variation on an identity transform -- that's a good place to start (+/- the "needlessly complex" part)  but it doesn't exhibit a *bona fide* effort to solve the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to translate the xml,just was thinking if there is any better easy way to implement.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ns3:Location">
        <xsl:variable name="locationName">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Name" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            <ns3:LocConditions>
                <xsl:for-each select="//ns3:PolicyConditions/ns3:PolicyCondition">
                    <xsl:for-each
                        select="ns3:PolicyConditionCriterias/ns3:PolicyConditionCriteria">
                        <xsl:if test="ns3:Value=$locationName">
                            <!--Zero or more repetitions: -->
                            <ns3:LocCondition>
                                <ns2:Id>0</ns2:Id>

                                <ns2:ConditionId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../ns2:ItemData" />

                                </ns2:ConditionId>
                            </ns3:LocCondition>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns3:LocConditions>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>



            <!-- template to copy elements -->
            <xsl:template match="*">
                            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
            <!-- template to copy attributes -->
            <xsl:template match="@*">
                            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:template>
            <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
            <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
                            <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:template>
```